# Why is this labeled javaScript continue not working?

Tags: javascript, continue, labeled-statements

I am using this code to weather some circles are overlapping:

```
iCantThinkOfAGoodLabelName:
x = genX(radius);
y = genY(radius);
for(i in circles) {
  var thisCircle = circles[i];
  if(Math.abs(x-thisCircle["x"])+Math.abs(y-thisCircle["y"])>radius*2) { //No overlap
    continue;
  } else { //Overlap
    continue iCantThinkOfAGoodLabelName; //<- Line 256
  }
  thisCircle = [];
}
```

But when the continue statement is reached, chrome's developer console gives me this: `client.html:256 Uncaught SyntaxError: Undefined label 'iCantThinkOfAGoodLabelName'`

Comment: Have you tried `break` instead of `continue`? Perhaps `continue` can only jump to a label that is on a loop statement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The label should come immediately before the loop

```
x = genX(radius);
y = genY(radius);

iCantThinkOfAGoodLabelName:
for(i in circles) {
```

Comment: In that case, any suggestion how I could then generate the X and Y values would be very helpful

Comment: edited - there's no reason you can't generate them before the label. The presence of the label doesn't affect those lines in any way.

Comment: Any reason why this wouldn't work? I've followed the instructions, but I'm just getting the same error.

Answer (score 7):

Because `iCantThinkOfAGoodLabelName:` needs to be right before the loop.

```
iCantThinkOfAGoodLabelName:
for (blah; blah; blah)
    ..
```

I think what you want is a function..

```
function iCantThinkOfAGoodFunctionName() {
    var x = genX(radius),
        y = genY(radius);

    for (i in circles) {
        var thisCircle = circles[i];
        if(Math.abs(x-thisCircle["x"])+Math.abs(y-thisCircle["y"])>radius*2) { //No overlap
            continue;
        } else { //Overlap
            iCantThinkOfAGoodFunctionName();
        }
        thisCircle = [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There should not be any statement between a label name and associated loop.

```
x = genX(radius);
y = genY(radius);
iCantThinkOfAGoodLabelName:
    for(i in circles) {
```

fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue and I resolved it by using all lowercase in the loop's label in version `v0.8.x` of Node.js.

Using `labelname:` vs. `iCantThinkOfAGoodLabelName:` might help you.

Others have correctly corrected you on the location of the label. It should be immediately before the `for` loop.

The [Mozilla Developer Network on labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) advises to avoid using labels, and instead prefer [calling functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) or [throwing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) an error. You might rethink your strategy on using them, if possible.

Example of calling a function depending on result:

```
var i, j;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {   
      if (i == 1 && j == 1) {
         // we want to ignore and continue
      } else {
         // do work with these variables from inside the doWork function
         // (scoped to whatever scope `this` for loop is in)
         doWork.call(this, i, j); 
      }
   }
}
```